# Combining array elements with " mark at both ends

Tags: php

I need to combine two or more array elements enclosed inside a double quotation mark...
Example:
 - Before -

```
[
 "Foo1",
 "\"Foo2",
 "Foo3",
 "Foo4\"",
 "Foo5"
]
```

-After -

```
[
 "Foo1",
 "\"Foo2 Foo3 Foo4\"",
 "Foo5"
]
```

Comment: Show what you've tried. Don't just pawn off your work on us

Comment: Ik this looks unformatted but I posted this using my phone :/

Comment: Also what is logic behind  of adding 2,3,4 element only of the array? why not others?

Comment: Because, I need to combine arguments of the command.

Comment: These elements are actually read as an array.

Comment: @CortexPE  what happen if array structure changed like :-`[
 "Foo1",
 "\"Foo2",
 "Foo3",
 "Foo5",
"Foo4\""
]`
or
`[ "Foo1", "\"Foo2", "Foo3", "Foo5", "Foo4\"","FOO6","foo7", "\"Foo8"]` and some other types lso

Comment: [ "Foo1, "\"Foo2 Foo3 Foo5 Foo4\"" ]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Below, `$source` and `$result` are the source and result respectively. I would use [`array_reduce()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-reduce.php)

```
$result = array_reduce($source, function($acc,$i) {
    static $append = false; // static so value is remembered between iterations

    if($append) $acc[count($acc)-1] .= " $i"; // Append to the last element
    else $acc[] = $i; // Add a new element

    // Set $append=true if item starts with ", $append=false if item ends with "
    if(strpos($i,'"') === 0) $append = true;
    elseif (strpos($i,'"') === strlen($i)-1) $append = false;

    return $acc; // Value to be inserted as the $acc param in next iteration
}, []);
```

[**Live demo**](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/c522c8cd0390962070ed3aedf8d3292a2a06ce60)

Comment: It works even if the user puts more than two elements to be combined :)

Answer (score 0):

```
function combine_inside_quotation($array)
{
    if(!is_array($array) || 0 === ($array_lenght = count($array))) {
        return [];
    }

    $i = 0;
    $j = 0;
    $output = [];
    $inside_quote = false;

    while($i < $array_lenght) {
        if (false === $inside_quote && '"' === $array[$i][0]) {
            $inside_quote = true;
            $output[$j] = $array[$i];
        }else if (true === $inside_quote && '"' === $array[$i][strlen($array[$i]) - 1]) {
            $inside_quote = false;
            $output[$j] .= ' ' . $array[$i];
            $j++;
        }else if (true === $inside_quote && '"' !== $array[$i][0] && '"' !== $array[$i][strlen($array[$i]) - 1]) {
            $output[$j] .= ' ' . $array[$i];
        } else {
            $inside_quote = false;
            $output[$j] = $array[$i];
            $j++;
        }
        $i++;
    }


    return $output;
}
```

Try this function it gives the output you mentioned.

[Live Demo](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/4b82260a19376b3e3345d18a7baf390e2d82f795)

Comment: "Uninitialized string offset"

Comment: use Demo link above, can't reproduce the Uninitialized string offset error, every thing work fine now,

Comment: Oh It works... Works just like @BeetleJuice 's Answer.